# Why does the filter method not seem to work the same way as splice does in this todo app?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, splice

I have a todo app in JS with the following functions:

This is part of a function that passes an id into an event listener to remove a todo

```
removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                removeTodo(todo.id)
                renderTodos(todos, filters)
            })
```

This function removes the todo - I've used 2 approaches, the findIndex way works great, it removes the todo and renders the new todos fine - I thought the filter approach I've commented would also work but it doesn't, it does remove the todo but it doesn't automatically update the list in the browser unless I refresh the page, while splice does it automatically, why could this happen? could it be waiting to update local storage before renderTodos starts reading the list? Just a note that in the example that didn't work I was passing newTodos into the save function, I just changed it to todos for the splice way.

```
const removeTodo = function (id) {
const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(function (todo) {
    return todo.id === id
})

if (todoIndex > -1) {
    todos.splice(todoIndex, 1)
}
// newTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
//     return todo.id !== id
// })
saveTodos(todos)
}
```

the todo list is saved in local storage

```
const saveTodos = function (todos) {
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
}
```

Here is the render function for information

```
const renderTodos = function (todos, filters) {
        const filteredTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
            const searchTextMatch = todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText)
            const hideCompletedMatch = !filters.hideCompleted || !todo.completed
            return searchTextMatch && hideCompletedMatch
        })
            
        const todosLeft = filteredTodos.filter(function (todo) {
            return !todo.completed
        })
        document.querySelector('#todos').innerHTML = ''
        document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(generateSummaryDom(todosLeft))

        filteredTodos.forEach(function (todo) {
            document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(generateTodoDom(todo))
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice()` mutates the `todos` array which you are then renderering, while `filter()` returns a new array which you are not making use of.

To make it work with `filter()` you will need to return the `newTodos` from the remove function and render the returned array, not the original `todos` array.

```
removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const newTodos = removeTodo(todo.id);
  saveTodos(newTodos)
  renderTodos(newTodos, filters);
})

const removeTodo = function (id) {
  return todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)
}

const saveTodos = function (todos) {
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the save function to use todos instead of newTodos in the working example, in the method that didn't work I was passing newTodos in.

Comment: The key being that you should pass `newTodos` to the render function as well

Comment: But why? the `saveTodos` method which runs, updates the todos array with the updated list in `newTodos`. So when I run the render function it should be pulling the updated data in the todos array.

Comment: I see nowhere in your render function that you retrieve the JSON from localStorage, you're just passing the `todos` array that you presumably have assigned to some global variable to render. Simply updating localStorage has no effect on any variables that previously were assigned values pulled from it.

Comment: Hmm so in the removeButton event listener, I'm calling renderTodos after saveTodos, I guess what you mean is that local storage of todos is being updated but the todos in memory aren't. That might explain why when I refresh the page and the todos are being read in it updates the list on screen. I think that might be it

Comment: That sounds very probable. You could update the assigned `todos` variable with `newTodos` in `save` or just pass the `newTodos` as indicated in the answer. (This is why `splice()` is 'working', it mutates the `todos` array in memory)

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning a variable does not have side-effects; reassigning one identifier has no effect on identifiers elsewhere. Doing

```
  newTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
    return todo.id !== id
  })
  saveTodos(todos)
}
```

means that you've put some results into `newTodos` without doing anything else with it. It doesn't get put into storage (or rendered, though how you render isn't shown).

Pass along the new filtered todos, and render (however you're doing it) from there - and don't forget to declare your variables.

```
  const newTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
    return todo.id !== id
  })
  saveTodos(newTodos);
  renderTodos(newTodos);
```

while taking `renderTodos` out of the immediate listener callback.

Comment: Sorry I changed the saveTodos call to use todos instead of newTodos in the working example, previously I had newTodos in there. I'll add the render call as well

Comment: The same logic seems to apply - just pass the filtered array to `saveTodos` and then to `renderTodos`

Comment: Yes based on the other answer + comments it seems that I might be updating localstorage but not reading it in till I manually refresh the page, I will test this out.