# How to enable a button to delete items in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a task that needs me to create a button that deletes certain items in an array. I have passed an array as a prop to the child component (). Now in the child component, whenever I click the delete button, it doesn't seem to work and I am struggling to find the problem.

Here's the link to the code:
(App.js)

```
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setList([...list, {val: input, key: Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)}]);
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
       setInput(e.target.value)
  }
  return(
    <div className='App'>
     <header className='App-header'>
       <div className='Wrapper'>
         <div className='input-container'>
         <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={input} />
         <input type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} />
         </div>
       <List list={list}/>
       </div>
     </header>
    </div>
  )
}


export default App;
```

And the link to the "" component that:

```
function List(props) {
    //handle delete. we return elements on a condition that the keys do not match
    const handleDelete = (key)=>{
        props.list.filter((items)=>{
            return items.key != key
        })
    }


  return (
      <>
          {
              props.list.map(function(listItem){
                  return (
                      <div className='lists' key={listItem.key}>
                          <p>{listItem.val}  <button onClick={handleDelete(listItem.key)}>Delete</button> </p>
                      </div>
                  )
              })
          }
      </>
  )
}

export default List
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the filter method not seem to work the same way as splice does in this todo app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72244226/why-does-the-filter-method-not-seem-to-work-the-same-way-as-splice-does-in-this)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `setList` to List component

```
<List list={list} setList={setList}/>
```

**List**

```
const handleDelete = (key)=>{
    const newList = props.list.filter((items)=>{
        return items.key != key
    })
    props.setList(newList)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` function is returning a new array, it is not modifying the existing array you have. Therefore, you have to assign the newly filtered list using the `setList` function. You can either pass the `setList` function as a prop to your child component to call it after filtering, or provide your child component a `handleDelete` callback function which you would define in the parent component (which will do the filtering and setting in the parent) via a prop, and then you just call it in the child component on click.